# Snapping to grid while using smart guides

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, snapping

[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html) it says I can't use `snap to grid` and `smart guides` at the same time:

> Note:
>   When Snap To Grid or Pixel Preview is turned on, you cannot use Smart Guides (even if the menu command is selected).

Now if I want to place an object at a different position to any smart guides, how can I assure that it is placed on "even" coordinates. Can I maybe add smart guides for every 80px vertically and horizontally? It bugs me that I have to manually adjust it afterwards all the time e.g. because it placed the object 0.002px too far to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a rectangle that surrounds the area where you want the guides.
2. Select rectangle and go to `Object -> Path -> Split Into Grid ...`
3. Set 80px for width and height and click OK.
4. Go to `View -> Guides -> Make Guides`